# Alternative to XmlDocument.Validate for validating againt a XSD

Tags: .net-core

I wonder if there is an alternative to `XmlDocument.Validate` for validating against an XSD.

The reason is the information provided about exceptions (validation errors) could be more detailed.

For example there could be indices or paths of validated elements or line numbers and positions, which are zero when using `XmlDocument.Validate`.

Comment: Those things don't apply to *parsed* documents just as source code lines don't apply to compiled binaries. That information is no longer there. Some elements may not have an order too, making indexes meaningless. The [XmlSchemaException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaexception?view=netframework-4.7.2) *does* contain line and position though. What did you try and what did you get?

Comment: Did you try [validating while loading the document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/validating-an-xml-document-in-the-dom#validating-an-xml-document-as-it-is-loaded-into-the-dom) ?

Comment: You *do* get the line number and position if you validate while loading

Comment: My mistake, I was validating a document with the `Validate` method after it was loaded with the `Load` method, I will try to use the XmlReader. Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parsed document doesn't reatin any source text information, just as a compiled program doesn't retain any source code information. To get that information one has to validate the document while loading it. Copying from the [validation documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/validating-an-xml-document-in-the-dom#validating-an-xml-document-as-it-is-loaded-into-the-dom), given this schema and xml string :

```
string xsdMarkup =  
    @"<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'>  
       <xsd:element name='Root'>  
        <xsd:complexType>  
         <xsd:sequence>  
          <xsd:element name='Child1' minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='1'/>  
          <xsd:element name='Child2' minOccurs='1' maxOccurs='1'/>  
         </xsd:sequence>  
        </xsd:complexType>  
       </xsd:element>  
      </xsd:schema>";  
XmlSchemaSet schemas = new XmlSchemaSet();  
schemas.Add("", XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xsdMarkup)));  

var xml=@"<Root>
  <Child1>content1</Child1>
  <Child3>content1</Child3>
</Root>";
```

The following code :

```
void ValidationHandler(object o,ValidationEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1} {2}", e.Exception.LineNumber,e.Exception.LinePosition,e.Message);  
}

XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
settings.Schemas=schemas;
settings.ValidationEventHandler += ValidationHandler;
settings.ValidationFlags = settings.ValidationFlags |
                           XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ReportValidationWarnings;
settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml), settings);            

XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
document.Load(reader);
```

Will print :

> 3:8 The element 'Root' has invalid child element 'Child3'. List of possible elements expected: 'Child2'.

The same code will work with an XDocument too :

```
var doc=XDocument.Load(reader);
```

Will print the same error.